# Where is the Commander tool window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use `Android Studio 1.5.1`. [Here](http://theappnewb.com/archives/2015/03/Introduction-to-Android-Studio-basic-contents-and-first-test/en/) I saw this image:

[image]

And this description:

> Commander: It′s the combination of the Project and Structure tools
>   that we saw earlier, ...

But I cannot see it. Also it is not in `View >> Tool Windows` menu. I tried to find this as a plugin for `JetBrains` as described here but [there](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/commander-tool-android-studio-t3198332) is not such plugin.
Is that gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article is almost a year old now.  Android Studio has changed and no longer includes that tool.  If you compare your Android Studio 1.5.1 to the screen shown in the article, you will spot many other little changes.